# For spring based microservices , How can we push and pull data from a Data lake. .How can you interact with data in data lake using microservices

Tags: microservices, data-lake

I want to create a spring based microservice architecture where I can receive some reviews about a product and want to store it to a data lake .And whenever I need it I want to retrieve it back from that Data Lake .So what additional programming should I require to push data  and get data from data lake . How a microservice can communicate with data stored in a Data Lake.

Comment: AFAIK data lake is an architectural/conceptual term which is mostly about keeping the data in raw format (blobs or files) so that later on it can be used for tasks such as analytics and machine learning. And what you are looking for seems to me just a simple database to manage your data.

Comment: Won't this article help? https://itnext.io/getting-data-to-data-lake-from-microservices-part-1-from-databases-d5e55c4a0829

Comment: Thanks  KrishPrabakar , Will refer to the link and revert asap